# Invalid pointer objects in an array (cloud code or iOS)

Tags: parse-platform

I'm not sure if this is the result of a cloud code issue or something in the app, but I'm having intermittent instances of improperly formatted pointers in an array of pointers.

example:

```
[{"objectId":"gUOJs00cvD"},{"objectId":"yd0LMMLQXf"}]
```

instead of:

```
[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"UserProfile", "objectId":"gUOJs00cvD"},{"__type":"Pointer","className":"UserProfile", "objectId":"yd0LMMLQXf"}]
```

Comment: how are you querying this info?

Comment: Probably an issue of copying/pasting directly from the data browser.

Comment: I'm seeing it in both the old dashboard, console.log()'s, and direct passing to response.success().

It is unlikely we are pasting in that field, but it is possible that we are editing other fields.  I'm not sure if we saw it before the new dash was being used, but some of us are using it.